# Creating Custom Settings on Pages/Posts For Plugin

Tags: plugins

I have been working on a plugin for a bit now. I have successfully created a Settings/Options page and have working settings fields, etc. on this page.

However, I also want the option to input data on individual pages. So, essentially, I need custom fields on individual pages (like /home/, /contact-us/, etc.) but I don't want to use the default Custom Fields built into WP. So, how do I add settings fields to individual pages, just like the ones I added to the settings page I made?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/). That function will allow you to create dedicated fields for saving meta data for posts, pages, etc.